# Media queries in CSS: display: none not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have problem with my code:

HTML

```
<section id="offer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-md-12">
                        <h2>Offer</h2>
                        <p>
                            <img src="images/offer_img.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-left offer-img">
                            Vestibulum tristique turpis ac ligula pellentesque
                        </p>
                        <h4>We have the best offer in this country!</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>morbi sollicitudin porttitor mi ac faucibus</li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>mi ullamcorper nisl laoreet placerat </li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>ut sem vitae dui bibendum</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>Pellentesque placerat ante sit amet augue sagittis, quis laoreet ipsum egestas. Vestibulum tristique turpis ac ligula pellentesque, sit amet luctus velit vehicula. Curabitur malesuada leo sit amet nisi sagittis, mattis fringilla dui commodo. Morbi fringilla risus ut massa varius, at faucibus nibh maximus</p>
                        <p>Maecenas venenatis nisi non erat efficitur dictum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I'm trying to hide this section when the screen resize to 400px or less. Here is my CSS- Media queries code.

```
@media all and(max-width:400px)
{
    .navbar-brand img
    {
        height: 63px;
    }

    #offer
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using !important can be dangerous, use it wisely :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use bootstrap to achieve this. Just fix your media query selector like so:

`@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {`

Also, make sure the viewport settings are set correctly with:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #offer{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap you add css class **hidden-sm** on h2 (Small devices
Tablets (≥768px) )

```
 <section id="offer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="hidden-sm">Offer</h2>
                    <p>
                        <img src="images/offer_img.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-left offer-img">
                        Vestibulum tristique turpis ac ligula pellentesque
                    </p>
                    <h4>We have the best offer in this country!</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>morbi sollicitudin porttitor mi ac faucibus</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>mi ullamcorper nisl laoreet placerat </li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>ut sem vitae dui bibendum</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Pellentesque placerat ante sit amet augue sagittis, quis laoreet ipsum egestas. Vestibulum tristique turpis ac ligula pellentesque, sit amet luctus velit vehicula. Curabitur malesuada leo sit amet nisi sagittis, mattis fringilla dui commodo. Morbi fringilla risus ut massa varius, at faucibus nibh maximus</p>
                    <p>Maecenas venenatis nisi non erat efficitur dictum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

For ≥400px

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
h2 { display: none !important; }  /* hide it on small screens */
}
```

Hope it's help

Remy